# Solving an equation that involves convolution and batch normalization

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution, batch-normalization

Basically the equation is

$$
x = \mathrm{BN}(\mathrm{Conv}(z))
$$

where the convolution operation uses SAME padding with stride $1$ ensuring that the input and output have the same size. The background description of the problem is to design a layer with forward propagation implicit. I was given a hint to use generalized minimal residual method, which is mainly designed for sparse linear systems. This is easy to understand for the convolution part, but what about the batch normalization? I find it hard to formulate it into a matrix multiplication or deriving its inverse function.

I tried to rewrite $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ as

$$\mu = \frac{\mathbf{1}^T X}{m}\text{ and }\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{m}X^T X+\frac{X^T \mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T X}{m}\left(1-\frac{2}{m}\right)$$

Then the equation $\mathrm{BN}(X) = Y$ can be written as

$$
\sigma\cdot(Y-\beta\mathbf{1}) = \gamma\left(X-\mathbf{1}\frac{\mathbf{1}^T X}{m}\right)\left(=\gamma\left(I-\frac{\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T}{m}\right)X\right)
$$

However $I_m-\frac{\mathbf{ones}_m}{m}$ is uninvertible. This is reasonable as when the mean of $X$ changes, the normalized output remains the same. So, is it that we do not need to care much about the normalization layer and instead just solve for $x = \mathrm{Conv}(z)$?

In addition, I am also asked to look for the gradients of $z$ w.r.t. the parameters of the convolution and batch normalization layers. I thought this would be approached once the forward propagation is dealt with but actually it is not. When deriving the back propagation of a regular convolution layer, the partial derivatives are easy to find and thus can be written in the form of convolution intuitively. However, as now the output are combined with parameters, the partial derivatives are much harder to find.

Well, this is actually a pre-interview question for a research group designed by some first year graduate students. I truly doubt if they have got an answer to this question.

Comment: what are you solving for?

Comment: I am solving for $z$, the output activation of the layer.

Comment: well neither batch norm nor convolution are injective functions so this is not possible